# Like message programmatically

Tags: message, odoo-8, vote

I need to like a message from website, i tried below code in controller file,

```
@http.route(["/web/like/comment"])
def likemsg(self):
    cr,uid = request.cr,request.uid
    pool = request.registry
    obj_msg = pool['mail.message']
    obj_mg.create(cr,uid,{'vote_user_ids':[(4, 0, uid)]})
```

i don't know how to pass msg_id in create method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution:

obj_msg.write(cr,uid,[msg_id],{'vote_user_ids':[(4,uid)]})